# Android CameraX throwing exception when enabling video capture usecase

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm using the CameraX for the first time, and following the android documentation guide, but having issues, search a lot but did not find anything helping, so basically I'm trying to capture screen using CameraX and my captureVideo() method code is,

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
public void takeVideo() {
    ContentValues contentValues;
    if (videoCapture == null) {
        return;
    }
    Recording curRecording = recording;
    if (curRecording != null) {
        // Stop the current recording session.
        recording.stop();
        recording = null;
        return;
    }

    // create and start a new recording session
    String name = DateFormat.getInstance().format(new Date().getTime()).toString();
    contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/CameraX-Video");
    }
    MediaStoreOutputOptions mediaStoreOutputOptions = new MediaStoreOutputOptions.Builder(getContentResolver(), MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            .setContentValues(contentValues)
            .build();
    PendingRecording pendingRecording = (videoCapture.getOutput()
            .prepareRecording(this, mediaStoreOutputOptions));
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        pendingRecording.withAudioEnabled();
        recording = pendingRecording.start(getMainExecutor(), new Consumer<VideoRecordEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(VideoRecordEvent videoRecordEvent) {
                if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Start) {
                    btnTakeVide.setText("Stop Video");
                } else if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Pause) {
                    // Handle the case where the active recording is paused
                } else if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Resume) {
                    // Handles the case where the active recording is resumed
                } else if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) {
                    btnTakeVide.setText("Start Video");
                    VideoRecordEvent.Finalize finalizeEvent =
                            (VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) videoRecordEvent;
                    // Handles a finalize event for the active recording, checking Finalize.getError()
                    if (!finalizeEvent.hasError()) {
                        String msg = "Video capture succeeded: " + ((VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) videoRecordEvent).getOutputResults().getOutputUri();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    } else {
                        if (recording != null) {
                            recording.close();
                            recording = null;
                            Log.e("TAG", "Video capture ends with error: ");
                        }
                      
                    }
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

code inside setPreview is,

```
private void startCameraPreview() {
    listenableFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
    listenableFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                cameraProvider = listenableFuture.get();
                preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
                preview.setSurfaceProvider(cameraView.getSurfaceProvider());
                recorder = new Recorder.Builder()
                        .setQualitySelector(QualitySelector.from(Quality.LOWEST))
                        .build();
                videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder);
                cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA;
                cameraProvider.unbindAll();
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(MainActivity.this, cameraSelector, preview, videoCapture);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));

}
```

the exception being thrown is,
[image]

I inserted following dependencies,

```
def camerax_version = "1.2.0-alpha04"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.1.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry developers, I forgot to add the video dependency,
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:${camerax_version}"
after adding dependency it works fine.